# AWS NextJS - InvalidParameterValueExcepetion (parameter of nodejs12.x) while Starting SSR Build

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-lambda, deployment, aws-amplify

I have a project deployed in AWS Amplify (us-east-1) with NextJS 12.3.4.

I was trying to update nextJS to 14.0.1 and couldn't so I reset the commits and versions, but now I can't deploy anymore.

(This is my first report, I don't know if I'm doing it right, please correct me if not)

Error Log:

```
2023-11-17T19:02:52.955Z [INFO]: # Executing command: node -v
2023-11-17T19:02:52.958Z [INFO]: v16.19.0
2023-11-17T19:02:52.959Z [INFO]: Starting SSR Build...
2023-11-17T19:05:18.001Z [ERROR]: InvalidParameterValueException: The runtime parameter of nodejs12.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs18.x) while creating or updating functions.
                                  at Object.extractError (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:80:27)
                                  at Request.extractError (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:61:8)
                                  at Request.callListeners (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
                                  at Request.emit (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
                                  at Request.emit (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
                                  at Request.transition (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
                                  at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
                                  at /root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
                                  at Request.<anonymous> (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
                                  at Request.<anonymous> (/root/./-patch.2/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12) {
                                  code: 'InvalidParameterValueException',
                                  '[Type]': 'See error.Type for details.',
                                  time: 2023-11-17T19:05:17.942Z,
                                  requestId: '41193a1e-ad7f-4f8d-bdb7-ffe22ec9adb6',
                                  statusCode: 400,
                                  retryable: false,
                                  retryDelay: 60.782903561879856
                                  }
2023-11-17T19:05:18.003Z [ERROR]: �[G�[?25h�[G�[J
                                  98s › d1vx5g7p91hfch › InvalidParameterValueException: The runtime parameter of nodejs12.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs18.x) while creating or updating functions.
                                  �[G�[?25h
Terminating logging...
```

Build Settings:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      comands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
        - node -v
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - 'node_modules/**/*'
      - '.next/cache/**/*'
```

### Expected behavior

In the "Front End" tab the compilation of the code, and the type verification is done correctly, but after that the SSR Build should also complete, but it does not happen.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIN5l.png)

### Reproduction steps

1. Remove NextJS from the project
2. Install NextJS 14.0.1
3. Upload changes
4. Seeing that they failed, I tried to roll back the changes (removing next and reinstalling in version 12.3.4)

### Attempts

I tried to put "Amazon Linux:2023" in
App settings => Build settings => Build image settings => Build image
And it shows all the green ticks, but the changes are not updated on my website

[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdxCd.png)

Previously I had some lambda functions with runtime Nodejs 12x.
Now all my lambda functions have the Nodejs 14x.
[Lambda List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMUCm.png)